# Using google-chrome-beta instead of stable in Protractor

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

When trying to run Protractor tests, I get an

`Error: SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 80`

Running Ubuntu with google-chrome stable version 79 and google-chrome-stable version 80 installed. Since I get the error, protractor seems to be trying to use the stable version, can I tell Protractor to use the beta version? Probably in the protractor.conf.js but not sure how, can't seem to find anything either.

Comment: I solved it by now, by copying the chrome-beta over to the chrome folder, so basically when chrome gets called the chrome-beta starts, not idea and I'd like a different solution, but for now it works.